# Preserving values between activities via Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bundle

I am using the following method to save the user inputted variables between activities:

```
  // Save instance between activities
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        Toast.makeText(searchParam.this, "onSaveInstanceState", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        savedInstanceState.putString("subject", selectedSubject);
        savedInstanceState.putString("priceBand", priceBand);
        savedInstanceState.putFloat("rating", starRating);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isCheck", checked);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

When the user selected the advanced options he/she is sent to the `advancedSearch.class` to perform other things via this method:

```
 public void listenerForAdvSearch()
    {
        // Initialize advanced options button
        Button advancedOptionsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedButton);
        advancedOptionsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent advancedOptions = new Intent(searchParam.this, advancedSearch.class);
                startActivity(advancedOptions);
            }
        });
    }
```

On return my onCreate method is called as follows:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(searchParam.this, "onCreate called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         if (savedInstanceState != null)
         {
            Toast.makeText(searchParam.this, "if savedInstanceState != NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            selectedSubject = savedInstanceState.getString("subject");
            priceBand = savedInstanceState.getString("priceBand");
            checked = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isCheck");
            starRating = savedInstanceState.getFloat("rating");
         }
         else
            Toast.makeText(searchParam.this, "if savedInstanceState = NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Call all listeners
        listenerForRatingBar();
        listenerForSubject();
        listenerForSearch();
        listenerForAdvSearch();
        listenerForGeoCheck();
        listenerForPrice();

    }
```

I have a couple toast messages in there for my personal debugging. My issue is in the if statement in the onCreate method; the savedInstanceState bundle is coming back as NULL and not restoring the values on return from the advanced options class. Why is this happening?

NOTE: here is the relevant code for advancedSearch class:

```
public class advancedSearch extends AppCompatActivity {

    // initialize variables
    int minute_x, hour_x;
    int year_x, month_x, day;
    static final int dialogid = 0;
    static final int tdialogid = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advanced_search);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Call picker dialogs on button click
        showDialogOnButtonClick();
        showTimeDialogOnButtonClick();

    }
```

Comment: Are you starting a different `Activity` or the same?

Comment: I am starting a new activity.

Comment: Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Bundle` to the `Intent` that you're starting the `Activity` from. `onSaveInstanceState()` won't work here. And inside the other `Activity`, use `getIntent().getExtras()` to get the `Bundle` to extract the values you've added.

`onSaveInstanceState()` is used to restore `Activity` state during recreation or configuration changes of the `Activity` that you're in, not across `Activity` to `Activity`.

That is:

Remove your override to `onSaveInstanceState()`.

When starting new `Activity`, pass in the data you need into the `Intent`:

```
public void listenerForAdvSearch()
{
    // Initialize advanced options button
    Button advancedOptionsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedButton);
    advancedOptionsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent advancedOptions = new Intent(searchParam.this, advancedSearch.class);
             advancedOptions.putExtra("subject", selectedSubject);
             advancedOptions.putExtra("priceBand", priceBand);
             advancedOptions.putExtra("rating", starRating);
             advancedOptions.putExtra("isCheck", checked);
             startActivity(advancedOptions);
         }
     });
}
```

Inside your new `Activity`, get the data from the `Bundle` inside the `Intent`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(searchParam.this, "onCreate called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Get your precious data
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    selectedSubject = bundle.getString("subject");
    priceBand = bundle.getString("priceBand");
    checked = bundle.getBoolean("isCheck");
    starRating = bundle.getFloat("rating");

    // Call all listeners
    listenerForRatingBar();
    listenerForSubject();
    listenerForSearch();
    listenerForAdvSearch();
    listenerForGeoCheck();
    listenerForPrice();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to pass data between two activities. You can achieve that adding data to `Intent`.

In the first activity add data using `putExtra(...)`:

```
public void listenerForAdvSearch()
{
    // Initialize advanced options button
    Button advancedOptionsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.advancedButton);
    advancedOptionsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent advancedOptions = new Intent(searchParam.this, advancedSearch.class);

            advancedOptions.putExtra("subject", selectedSubject);
            advancedOptions.putExtra("priceBand", priceBand);
            advancedOptions.putExtra("isCheck", checked);
            advancedOptions.putExtra("rating", starRating);

            startActivity(advancedOptions);
        }
    });
}
```

And retrieve the values in the second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    selectedSubject = getIntent().getStringExtra("subject");
    priceBand = getIntent().getStringExtra("priceBand");
    checked = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isCheck");
    starRating = getIntent().getFloatExtra("rating");
}
```